# Is writing bytes at the end of EXE file safe?

Tags: file, byte, executable, exe

I've heard that if we append some bytes at the end of an EXE file, it can still work properly. Is it true in all case? And is it a safe way?

I intend to write the demo using data in the program execution file, so it can be safe (at least to normal user) and I don't have to store data anywhere else.

Comment: Why not use resources for that data? That's what they are for....

Comment: @Etienne de Martel No, if I use resource, the program must create a XML file for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is impossible to answer with a certain Yes or No.

I assume you will store data at the end of your executable in lieu of storing program state in a configuration file. I further assume you're **doing this for fun** and the end result does not need to be perfect.

Any [code signing mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing) that might be in place on your platform will cry foul with these sorts of tricks. The signatures will only be valid if the executable does not materially change. (At least, in the [code signing mechanism I helped implement](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.27.4099&rank=1), the cryptographic signature was computed over the entire contents of the executable -- with the exception of the signature itself -- not just segments marked as executable or data in the program headers.)

Any anti-virus mechanisms that might be in place on your platform will cry foul with these sorts of tricks. [Self-modifying code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code) is definitely associated with programs attempting to remain hidden or obscure, and code that writes to itself is going to trigger alarms in behavioral anti-virus tools.

Tools such as [tripwire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Tripwire) or [`mtree`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mtree&sektion=8) will always complain about your program. `rpm -qa` or `debsums` will always report problems with your executable. It will be difficult to reliably transfer this program from site to site.

The permissions on standard executables in most environments would outright forbid this behavior. User accounts do not have privileges to modify most executables on the system -- only executables *owned* by the user that will run the executable could be written as well. (And even then, a  [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) system such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/) could forbid a process from writing to the program file, if properly configured. And almost every reasonable security profile would forbid it.)

No system administrator would let *two* users execute **and** write to the executable.

You also have the pragmatic problem of *finding the executable file in the first place*. At least Linux provides `/proc/self/exe`, but (a) system administrators may not have it mounted (b) system administrators may not let most processes *use* it (c) if the executable file is replaced while the program is executing finding the correct file to modify may be difficult.

You have to decide between two methods of updating the executable: either you *modify* the existing file (`ftell(3)` and `fseek(3)`) or you write the changed contents to a new file and *replace* the executable. Both approaches are troublesome: if you modify the file, you might have several copies executing simultaneously, trying to write conflicting edits to the file. Clever programming can avoid huge problems, but the entire executable might not be in a *consistent* state. If you replace the file, you might have several copies executing simultaneously, and the disk copies of the executable might not be *freed* and actually removable until the system is rebooted. You could have a dozen copies of your executable program file invisibly taking up disk space. None of them could *share memory* while executing, increasing memory pressure.

Yes, it's possible to keep configuration data in the program executable, and even make it work in some environments. But it isn't production-quality.

Answer (score 0):

If the compiler-linker, that is used with source code to produce
the final .exe file, is "healthy" and installed correctly, then
all the binary commands and links between them are located in
the space between the first and the last points of that .exe
file.
Therefore, any non-exe. file can be safely "attached" to the .exe
file at the tail of that .exe file.