# Modify exe bytes at runtime to make file MD5 unique from last runtime

Tags: c++

Each time I run the file I want the md5 to be unique without manually changing bytes in the compiler.

So how can I append some useless bytes to an .exe either on runtime or via another program?

Comment: Are you trying to build some kind of virus? :(

Comment: Worst idea ever. Don't do it. Please state the problem you are **really** trying to solve.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda No, I'm not

Comment: Good luck modifying the file whilst it is running. What's more two different files can have the same md5.

Comment: Things don't like it when exe's modify themselves.

Comment: @IInspectable Heh. Okay, the program I'm trying to solve is to make the program different from last runtime. I figured the easiest way to do it was to append some useless bytes. It doesn't really matter if it does it on runtime or if I would need to run a second program first to change the first program. Either way works, but doing it on runtime would be the smoothest.

Comment: @NeilKirk Neither proactive defense in antivirus software likes thing like this.

Comment: I know it sounds fishy, but it's for personal use, whether you believe me or not.

Comment: @Zute Ok, why you do need the file be different for each time it runs?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda To prevent recognition from AntiCheat and similar software

Comment: You can append any random bytes (`fopen("a.exe", "a")`, and then `fwrite`), they will be ignored by Windows when running the executable.

Comment: On Windows, add a custom binary resource of the required size and update it from an external process, before/after the application runs. This ensures that the binary will remain in a consistent state, and the OS loader will not barf.

Comment: @Zute Ohh man, do not cheat!  Your problem is not about programming, you need to practice and get better in the game in which you're trying to cheat.

Comment: @pts and what about the PE checksum?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda: The people who write anti-cheat software need to know about this possibility, in order to defend against it.  The question is just fine.  There are plenty of other valid uses for unique signatures on binaries, too.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda Bad habit, I know. Don't hit me. I need to dig deeper into C++ and I figured this would be a fun way to do it.

Comment: @David: The PE checksum is usually not calculated for user-mode applications. It is required for kernel-mode drivers (and some system DLLs). By default, the [/RELEASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8ksa72a.aspx) linker option is not set.

Comment: @IInspectable Are you sure. I recall having been bitten by this in the past when I've modified executables using, e.g. hex editors.

Comment: @David: I just opened random executables compiled by me, and all of them have a *Checksum* entry of 0x00000000 (located at offset 0x38). All of which were *Release* configurations, both 32 and 64 bit applications. You can also use `dumpbin /HEADERS <myapp.exe>` to see this for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Windows has a set of functions designed for this, the central one is `UpdateResource`.

MSDN also has an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources

However, you can't do this on a running program.  You may put the code to scramble the resource content into a separate EXE, or a DLL spawned with RUNDLL32.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is how I solved it very easily.
Created a second program that runs this piece of code

```
char asd[100];

FILE* cfile = fopen("program.exe", "a");
fwrite(asd, 1, sizeof(asd), cfile);
fclose(cfile);
```

This successfully changes the MD5 of the program.

Comment: See [is writing bytes to the end of an EXE file safe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6341256/211160)

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning earlier, open in binary mode (`"ab"` instead of `"a"`) to predictably write 100 bytes.